# Magento multistore issue when switching from secondary store

Tags: magento

I have set up 2 stores under one Magento installation using this method:
http://webdevster.com/ecommerce/magento/magento-multiple-store-setup-instructions

Each store has it's own URL ie. http://mainstore.com and http://secondarystore.com (add on domain in cpanel)

If I navigate to to mainstore and then switch to secondarystore using the store switcher everything works as expected.  I can log in on the secondary and remain there.

The problems arise if I navigate directly to secondarystore in the beginning.  If I do this and then try logging in I get automatically redirected to http://mainstore.com/customer/account/login/

Does anyone know why things only work correctly if I navigate to http://mainstore.com and then switch to the secondary store?

**EDIT:**
I've noticed that if I access the secondary store using secondarystore.com?**_store=secondstore instead of just secondarystore.com it works perfectly. Anyone know how to get the same results without needing the ?**_store=secondstore?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup seperate Apache vhost entries for each URL. You use the same document root for both.  In each one, you should have a set of  lines like:

```
SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE=base
SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

Change 'base' with the actual website code you set in the admin for the second site.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with my setup.  I've noticed that if I access the secondary store using http://secondarystore.com?___store=secondstore instead of just http://secondarystore.com it works perfectly.  Anyone know how to get the same results without needing the ?___store=secondstore?

Comment: So in the vhost for secondarystore.com you added: 'SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE=secondstore'?